Why do basketballs with more air in them bounce more than ones with less air?
I thought it this because more air means more pressure, so there will be more pressure when the ball is deformed and it will gain more kinetic energy as it rebounds. However, some sources say that balls with less air deform more and lose more energy to heat, so balls with more air deform less and lose less energy to heat. Another source says balls with more air (more pressure) hit the ground with more force, so the reaction force from the ground is greater. Are any of these correct?

It's not really the force that matters, but the impulse

Re, "balls with less air deform more and lose more energy to heat." Yes. See @Whit3rd's answer. An important concept is hysteresis. The envelope material of the ball is more hysteretic than the air that fills it. The air gives back relatively more of the energy that it absorbs when the ball hits the floor than what the envelope gives back. So, less deformation of the envelope means less energy lost.

I think the answer is that the rubber is less elastic than the fill air.
When the pressure is high, a typical bounce will flex the
rubber of the basketball a few millimeters on a bounce, while it can be
centimeters if pressure is low.   There's more energy loss in
the greater flexure.
Air is fluid, deforms readily and compresses/expands so efficiently
that sounds can be heard from miles away.   A mile of sound-travel  in
air is a great number of compression/decompression cycles, and
no dropped basketball will make a comparable number of bounces before
coming to a halt.

I think it's because in the high pressure case, the rubber in the ball is more preloaded in tension.  The rubber behaves like a spring, and with the internal pressure load its equilibrium state is one that is stretched. When the impact with the ground deforms the ball slightly, it wants to return to a position of high tension, which causes the spring-back.  Another way to say it is that the pressure loading makes the rubber "spring" more elastic.
Also, a less pressurized ball tends to buckle inward under impact rather than store energy in the tension of the rubber.  The high pressure prevents the buckling.

Does any of this relate to Newton's third law (for instance, does a ball with higher air pressure hit the ground with more force)?

No.  You can throw both types of ball with the same force.  Newton's 3rd law is a near useless statement in my opinion, and seems to hinder more than help understanding.  It is more about how to conceptualize what a force actually is, in a time in history when this was not obvious. With our modern education and study of forces, it is rather redundant

Maybe I'm completely confused, but I was thinking that if the same force was applied to both balls, yet the one with greater pressure has more mass, wouldn't it accelerate less due to Newton's second law (or more due to gravity)? I know this is a random question but I'm struggling to understand this concept. I just started learning it this year.

That's true, but the difference in mass is extremely small.  Air doesn't have much mass compared to the ball itself.  That is not what causes the difference in behavior.  If you are just starting to learn mechanics, a basketball is not the simplest example to analyze.  There's a reason the subject is taught using inclined planes, blocks, and springs.
